# Multiple statements in where clause, records newer than 3 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a column in my table called finished which is '0' by default. But when a user press a butten, it updates white the current date. In a view I want to see records which is either 0 or a date that is newer than 3 weeks.

When I use this code:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT TOP 100 [ID]
  ,[week]
  ,[dayNumb]
  ,[oven]
  ,[section]
  ,[finished]
  ,convert(datetime, [finished], 104)
  ,dateadd(week,-3,getdate())
  ,isdate(convert(datetime, [finished], 104))
FROM [MurergruppeDB].[dbo].[jobPlan]
where [finished] like 0 or convert(datetime, [finished], 104) > dateadd(week,-3,getdate())
```

I get the error message: Syntax error converting datetime from character string.
When i dont use the statement after or in the where clause, i get fine datetimes in all the result (when [finished] not like 0), so i think the server is trying to convert the 
records which is 0 before also.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you end up trying to convert '0' to a date, '0' is not a valid date.

You need to handle force it to compare dates only when the field is a date:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT TOP 100 [ID]
  ,[week]
  ,[dayNumb]
  ,[oven]
  ,[section]
  ,[finished]
  --,convert(datetime, [finished], 104)
  --,dateadd(week,-3,getdate())
  --,isdate(convert(datetime, [finished], 104))
FROM [MurergruppeDB].[dbo].[jobPlan]
where [finished] like 0 
   or CASE WHEN ISDATE([finished]) = 1 THEN convert(datetime, [finished], 104) END  
      > dateadd(week,-3,getdate())
```

Ideally you wouldn't default to '0'.  NULL or even '' would work in this case, as '' as a DATE is `1900-01-01` which can be a useful default in some situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been trying with Case but could't figure out how, so I really belive in this answer. I will test it tomorrow morning and mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: Finally it worked! I just had to remove those three last selections from your answer and then it worked!

Comment: That makes sense, wasn't sure why they were in your original.

Answer (score 0):

"0" is not a valid date so the conversion convert(datetime, [finished], 104) fails. There's no short-circuiting in SQL Server like in C++/C#.

I suggest using NULL instead of 0. This is what NULLs are for.

The where clause then becomes:

```
where [finished] IS NULL OR convert(datetime, [finished], 104) > dateadd(week,-3,getdate())
```

The CONVERT function will happily take a NULL for [finished] and the expression convert(datetime, [finished], 104) > dateadd(week,-3,getdate()) will evaluate to False.

Comment: Good idea, too bad I didn't allow the column to have null, when i made the table. But i think that would be better database model ethic, for my further projects.